# Insert new row between data

Tags: vba, excel

In cells A1 and A3 i have data. If I insert a new data in cell A2, I need a new row to be inserted between A2 and A3, so that A3 will always remain at the bottom (will be moved to A4..and so on). 
I looked everywhere but what I found was a different need for the insert. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you need a code, try recording a macro while you do it manually. It will give you some code to start with.

Comment: Show your VBA code so far.

Comment: First find your last used row number.  There are thousands of examples how to do that on the net.  If you need to add data to column A then insert new row at the last used row number.  This will push the last row to the next row number and you can put your new data into the row that was the last used row number but is now the next to last used row.

Comment: @JohnMuggins After reading your comment, I added into my answer about finding dynamically the last row for the loop.  Good addition.  I know lots of folks are not familiar with manipulating the loop by specifying the Step part of the function.

Comment: What i have so far but doesn't really work properly is: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LA As Long
LA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & LA).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
End Sub

Comment: [mcve] is the magic piece

Comment: I think this is more of a logic problem than a code problem.  There are always a dozen different ways to skin a cat.  In this case the OP was trying to use a sledge hammer instead of a scalpel.....  Sometimes they just need finesse to show them how the scalpel can work better than a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody, i did it with some small changes:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common problem, and is solved by looping.

You need to specify the Step of your loop function, e.g.:

```
For i = 100 to 2 Step -1

'Code... soemthign like If Cells(i,1).Value>0 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert End If

Next i
```

This will go in reverse order, which removes the issue of the lines moving down.

You can also make the last row dynamic (I'll leave you to find that code... quick google search turns it up, usually).  The For statement would look like:

```
Dim LR as Long
LR = 'dynamic code
For i = LR to 1 Step -1
'Code
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment above I can see that you weren't in the worng ball park.  There are probably a dozen ways or so to find your last used row.  Here are a couple:

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).row
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

And here is the code that will accomplish the task.

```
Sub tester1()
Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "Done!"

End Sub
```